# How do I hide likes and posts from specific friends on my timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

How can I hide likes, posts, etc. from specific friends? Unfortunately I cannot unfriend them since some of them are my colleagues but I would really like to hide their posts, likes or activities.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the person's profile and click "Following" to remove the checkmark.

[image: Facebook profile]

You'll remain friends with the person, but their updates etc. will not find their way to your feed.

[Facebook Help: Follow](https://www.facebook.com/help/382751108453953/)